# Changing values inside Python Modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have a simple Python module file `First.py`:

```
a = 50
b = [100,200,300]
```

I try to import this module into another file `Test.py`:

```
import First
First.a = 420
First.b[0] = 420
print (First.a)
```

My purpose is to change the list values inside the First module.

Once the script `Test.py` completes when I print the values inside the module , I find that the values have not changed.

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (I
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import First
>>> dir(First)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__',
'__package__', '__spec__', 'a', 'b']
>>> First.a
50
>>> First.b
[100, 200, 300]
```

What am I missing here? Can someone kindly guide me?

Comment: Any changes are in the runtime, they are not persistent between sessions. The text of the module is not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once the script `Test.py` completes when I print the values inside the module , i find that the values have not changed.

If you executed `python Test.py`, *then* fired up your interpreter interactively and checked the values, of course, modifications won't be visible. Python just loads `First.py` when the `import` is found, executing it and initializing `a` and `b` with the values in `First.py`; previous executions won't affect this.

If you import `Test` in your interactive interpreter and *then* import `First` changes will be reflected:

```
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Test
420
>>> import First
>>> First.a
420
>>> First.b
[420, 200, 300]
```

During the import of `Test`, `First` was loaded and executed, then its values modified. When you re-import python will just look in a table of imported modules (`sys.modules`) and return it without executing its content (and re-initializing `a` and `b`)

Comment: But i am not sure i follow 100%. According to my understanding Python does not reload and run a module file once it is already loaded and .pyc file is created. So why in the first case the module code is re-run which ultimately reinitialize the variables and the code is not run the second time. In both the cases the module is already loaded.

Comment: @SubhayanBhattacharya Yes, `.pyc` files are generated but that makes no difference. When you run (not import) `Test.py` changes it made to `First.py` aren't persistent; the `.pyc` file has the *same* bytecode instructions. When you `import Test` you also `import First` and *then* change its value, the `.pyc` doesn't really play a role here :-).